# Centerize things

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't this center the words? I added both justify-content and align-items.

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px;
}

#item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div id='item'>
    <h4>why doesn't this work</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You HTML is not valid. You need to close the div I made a snippet for you and closed the div

Comment: add border around h4 to understand, here you need text-align:center